# Finding empty columns of a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, schema, database-design, null

What query would return the name of the columns of a table where all rows are NULL?

Comment: Do you mean a particular table, or all tables in a schema?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Sounds like you have too many columns/tables and should rethink your design.

Answer (score 14):

testbed:

```
create role stack;
create schema authorization stack;
set role stack;

create table my_table as 
select generate_series(0,9) as id, 1 as val1, null::integer as val2;

create table my_table2 as 
select generate_series(0,9) as id, 1 as val1, null::integer as val2, 3 as val3;
```

function:

```
create function has_nonnulls(p_schema in text, p_table in text, p_column in text)
                returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
declare 
  b boolean;
begin
  execute 'select exists(select * from '||
          p_table||' where '||p_column||' is not null)' into b;
  return b;
end;$$;
```

query:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name, 
       has_nonnulls(table_schema, table_name, column_name)
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='stack';
```

result:

```
 table_schema | table_name | column_name | has_nonnulls
--------------+------------+-------------+--------------
 stack        | my_table   | id          | t
 stack        | my_table   | val1        | t
 stack        | my_table   | val2        | f
 stack        | my_table2  | id          | t
 stack        | my_table2  | val1        | t
 stack        | my_table2  | val2        | f
 stack        | my_table2  | val3        | t
(7 rows)
```

In addition you can get an approximate answer by querying the catalog - if `null_frac` is zero that indicates no nulls but should be double-checked against 'real' data:

```
select tablename, attname, null_frac from pg_stats where schemaname='stack';

 tablename | attname | null_frac
-----------+---------+-----------
 my_table  | id      |         0
 my_table  | val1    |         0
 my_table  | val2    |         1
 my_table2 | id      |         0
 my_table2 | val1    |         0
 my_table2 | val2    |         1
 my_table2 | val3    |         0
(7 rows)
```

Comment: This is a hella old question, but folks who use spatial extensions (postgis) should note that empty spatial columns don't appear in `pg_stats` if they are empty at table creation. I found this out today when doing some housekeeping. I discovered that some historical *aspatial* tables had been imported using `ogr2ogr`. if there's no spatial column in the data being imported, `ogr2ogr` creates a geometry column full of `<NULL>`. My `pg_stats` has no geometry columns from the imported aspatial tables (it has all the other columns for those tables). Quite odd, I thought.

Answer (score 12):

In Postgresql, you can get the data directly from the stats:

```
vacuum analyze; -- if needed

select schemaname, tablename, attname
from pg_stats
where most_common_vals is null
and most_common_freqs is null
and histogram_bounds is null
and correlation is null
and null_frac = 1;
```

You might get a few false positives, so a recheck is in order after finding the candidates.

Comment: Do you need any other conditions than `null_frac=1`?

Comment: I'm not sure. null_frac presumably is a real, so it might be that it rounds to 1 in some odd cases. But even with 1 out of 10k rows, it would result in something that fits.

Comment: This was a great solution and it worked perfectly for me. I did add a where clause to only show tables from my public schema.

Comment: What an interesting solution. This one is great for finding pesky nulls-that-shouldn't-be in Entity Framework Core (and potentially other ORM's) that will complain _very loudly_ if the model class doesn't explicitly tell they should be permitted.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you my solution in T-SQL, working for SQL Server 2008. I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, but I hope that you'll find some guidance in my solution.

```
-- create test table
IF object_id ('dbo.TestTable') is not null
    DROP table testTable
go
create table testTable (
    id int identity primary key clustered,
    nullColumn varchar(100) NULL,
    notNullColumn varchar(100) not null,
    combinedColumn varchar(100) NULL,
    testTime datetime default getdate()
);
go

-- insert test data:
INSERT INTO testTable(nullColumn, notNullColumn, combinedColumn)
SELECT NULL, 'Test', 'Combination'
from sys.objects
union all
SELECT NULL, 'Test2', NULL
from sys.objects

select *
from testTable

-- FIXED SCRIPT FOR KNOWN TABLE (known structure) - find all completely NULL columns
select sum(datalength(id)) as SumColLength,
    'id' as ColumnName
from dbo.testTable
UNION ALL
select sum(datalength(nullColumn)) as SumColLength,
    'nullColumn' as ColumnName
from dbo.testTable
UNION ALL
select sum(datalength(notNullColumn)) as SumColLength,
    'notNullColumn' as ColumnName
from dbo.testTable
UNION ALL
select sum(datalength(combinedColumn)) as SumColLength,
    'combinedColumn' as ColumnName
from dbo.testTable
UNION ALL
select sum(datalength(testTime)) as SumColLength,
    'testTime' as ColumnName
from dbo.testTable

-- DYNAMIC SCRIPT (unknown structure) - find all completely NULL columns
declare @sql varchar(max) = '', @tableName sysname = 'testTable';

SELECT @sql +=
        'select sum(datalength(' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ')) as SumColLength,
    ''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''' as ColumnName
from ' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + c.TABLE_NAME --as StatementToExecute
+ '
UNION ALL
'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = @tableName;

SET @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql)-11)
print @sql;
exec (@sql);
```

What I did, in short, was to create a test table with 5 columns, ID and testTime being generated by identity and getdate() function, while the 3 varchar columns being the ones of interest. One will have only NULL values, one will not have any NULLs, the other will be a combined column. The final result of the script will be that the script will report the column nullColumn as having all rows NULL.

The idea was to calculate the function [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) for each column (calculates the number of bytes for a given expression). So I calculated the DATALENGTH value for each row of each column and made a SUM per column. If the SUM per column is NULL, then the complete column has NULL rows, otherwise there is some data inside.

Now you have to find the translation for PostgreSQL and hopefully a colleague will be able to help you with that. Or maybe there is a nice system view that will show how dumb I am for reinventing the wheel :-).

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the information catalog for such information:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='your_table'
```

gives you the matching tables for your columns.

I don't have a postgres installation currently at hand but the rest should be simple

```
   loop over the results of the above query and foreach result
        send a COUNT(*) to the table
        if the count is null, give back the column,
                 else ignore it
   end foreach
```

Comment: This is working, but it's an iterative approach :-). I prefer the set based approach.

Answer (score 0):

After combining from several resources, I came up with this function and query to find all the empty columns in all the database tables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.isEmptyColumn(IN table_name varchar, IN column_name varchar)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
declare 
    count integer;
BEGIN
    execute FORMAT('SELECT COUNT(*) from %s WHERE %s IS NOT NULL', table_name, quote_ident(column_name)) into count;
    RETURN (count = 0);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL; 


SELECT s.table_name, s.column_name
FROM information_schema.columns s
WHERE (s.table_schema LIKE 'public') AND
      (s.table_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%') AND
      (public.isEmptyColumn(s.table_name, s.column_name))
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: As an absolute beginner with SQL, I found this page while trying to filter if a column is or isn't null.

This answer gave me the syntax I was looking for:
`SELECT * from public."Projects" where "link" IS NULL` and 
`SELECT * from public."Projects" where "link" IS NOT NULL`